# What are 'two way' magnets and how do they work?

Tags: electromagnetism

[Thomas & Friends Take-n-Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_&_Friends_merchandise#Take-n-Play_Thomas_.26_Friends) series connect to each other via something described as 'two way' magnets:

> the new models use special 'two-way' magnets

As a parent of an owner of two engines of the said series I can attest that indeed the magnets seem to ignore polarity. They attract each other in any combination and, furthermore, they attract 'classical' magnets both N pole and S pole.

I suspect this is some alloy that is capable of rapidly re-aligning its [magnetic domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain), but is just speculation. I couldn't find any reference to something called 'two-way' magnets nor anything else describing the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: I don't know this toy. Is it possible that these magnets are inside a cover and, inside it, they rotate when you get two of them closer? Another possibility: Is it possible that you have a special magnet and then every other "magnets" (just made of iron) is attracted to this special object?

Comment: I thought about a rotating core, but there is no evidence of any movement or shift inside them when they in vicinity of other magnets. They also attract any non-magnetized piece of iron, so they are not merely 'passive'.

Comment: My guess would be that the material is a realively soft ferrgnetic material. That means that it has a slim hysteresis curve. It should have a lower remanence than the PMs that are used for attracting it. So it basically is a nicely tuned alloy. If the PM is the same size as the two-way thingy you can compare the mass that they can lift.

Comment: I cant take the toy appart for experiments :) the would be many tears. But is definetely weaker than a PM of same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the answer but ya ain't gonna like it :-) .  Learning Curve holds [patents](http://patents.justia.com/patent/6722941) on a construct containing a disk magnet between two metal "pole pieces"  .  Quoting:

> One of the problems that exists with the couplers described in Östhall
>   and Eichorn et al. is their inability to hold the connection when the
>   toy vehicles are climbing ascending track segments or traveling on
>   curved track segments. The magnetic couplers of Östhall and Eichorn et
>   al. have a tendency to separate from each other due to the increased
>   stress on the connections which results from these situations. Another
>   problem is that two toy vehicles can be connected in a single
>   orientation. ... SUMMARY OF THE INVENTION The present invention
>   provides a novel magnetic coupler for joining a first toy vehicle to a
>   second toy vehicle. A magnetic coupler includes a first connector and
>   a disk-shaped magnet for joining the first toy vehicle to the second
>   toy vehicle. The first connector has a substantially frustoconical
>   shape. The first connector extends from an end wall of the first toy
>   vehicle. The frustoconical connector also has an aperture for
>   receiving a fastening element. The aperture is countersunk so that the
>   head of the fastening element is flush with the frustoconical
>   connector. The fastening element is used to mount the disk-shaped
>   magnet on the frustoconical connector. The disk-shaped magnet also has
>   a fastener opening for receiving the fastener. The disk-shaped magnet
>   is oriented so that is perpendicular to the end wall of the first
>   vehicle. Other advantages and aspects of the present invention will
>   become apparent upon reading the following description of the drawings
>   and detailed description of the invention.

The drawings are available [here](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/6722941.pdf)

FWIW,  my original guess (polarity perpendicular to direction of travel) was not that far off. :-)

Comment: The magnets stick out enough to test the attraction on all sides (left, right, up, down). They attract equally well a 'classic' PM on any side, and there is never any  rejection force to be felt.

Comment: Indeed, I was hoping for something less mechanical :)